# R - raster function NAs values lower than -9999 in ASCII file

Tags: r, import, ascii, raster

I have been having problems importing a ASCII raster that has values that go from `Min. :-69826220` to  `Max.   :167780500`. The problem I am encountering is that when I use the raster function to import the ASCII file then every value smaller than `-9999` is reported as `NA` and the minimum value is `-9458`.

Is this a bug of the function and is there a workaround? When I import the same ASCII file as a data frame everything is fine and I get the whole range of values.
Also I am using the same procedure to import other ASCII rasters and don't have any problem.

here is the link to the ASCII file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24234831/ps0011yme.asc

Here is the session info, I opened a new session just in case.

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
>   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] raster_2.1-16 sp_1.0-8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.0      lattice_0.20-15

Any help is appreciated

Comment: And if you run `minValue(x)` and `manValue(x)` where `x` is your raster what do you get?

Comment: I get for both the same result 
[1] NA
Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) : min/max value not known, use setMinMax

Comment: Why don't you give us the results of `summary( scan( "path/to/myraster.asc" , skip = 6 ) )`

Comment: I have just added a link to the file. It's a small ASCII.

Comment: Read 242640 items
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-69830000   -792300     -9999  11950000   4520000 167800000

Comment: I have udpated my answer. Please read it. Do you have `rgdal` installed? e.g. `library( rgdal )`

Comment: Install `rgdal` and try again: `install.packages("rgdal")`

Comment: Simon! Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy! Could you please add to your answer why in the world rgdal is needed in this case, just for completeness? Can I give you like 50 karma points or something? :)

Comment: lol for the karma points! ha ha. Glad you are no longer going crazy! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `setMinMax()` on your raster file to try and work out the min and max values and store them in the returned Raster* object. Try it like so:

```
r <- setMinMax( raster("path/to/myraster.asc") )
```

I am not sure what is happening because if I downlaod you data and do:

```
r1 <- raster( "~/Downloads/test.asc")
summary(values(r1))
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.      NA's 
-69830000  -4789000    737300  16950000  13880000 167800000     71468
```

Please add the output of `sessionInfo()` *into your question* , i.e. not as a comment.

The errors in this case were being caused by not having `rgdal` installed, which are bindings to the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library and are very important for importing/exporting raster and shapefile data.

Comment: I just tried both and this is what I get > setMinMax(ps0011yme)
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 337, 720, 242640  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)

but it is not working I have the same issue
extent      : -180, 180, -78.5, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : C:path\ps0011yme.asc 
names       : layer 
values      : -9458.911, 167780500  (min, max)

Comment: I am still wondering under what specific situations rgdal is needed because so far I have never run into any issue with raster/shapefile data. Is it because the values in this ASCII are so large?

Comment: @user4050 possibly - I cannot exactly say. I think it is always best to have `rgdal` installed though when one is working with spatial data.

Comment: A bit of a guess from my side, but I guess that raster has its own built-in ascii reader, and can use the rgdal one. When the rgdal one is installed, that one is used. Probably the rgdal one can deal with the data the OP encounters, and the built-in does not. This would explain why you need rgdal in this case. But to be sure the OP needs to explore the raster docs a bit more, or the source code.

Comment: @Paul: when I tried to tell `raster` to read a `.asc` file I thought it told me  I had to load the `rgdal` library.  Lost my history, so can't confirm for sure.

Comment: From the comments of the OP it seemed that he was able to read ascii files in the past without rgdal, but I haven't used raster a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to reproduce your error.  Here's a hand-built .asc file:

```
NCOLS 3 
NROWS 3 
XLLCORNER 0 
YLLCORNER 0 
CELLSIZE 0.5 
NODATA_value -9999 
1e-6 0.3 -34567891234
0.2 -1e6 25
3 68492758321934 20
```

That loaded correctly into a `raster` object.  You'll notice the `NODATA_value` item there, which explains where your -9999 come from.  My bet is that there's something corrupted in your source .asc file.  Can you post the header and a small sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

The internal ascii file driver in 'raster' assumes that there are no valid values lower than the NA flag value if the flag value is < 0 (and I would not recommend using an NA flag in the middle of the values). Clearly, this approach can cause problems like in this case; and I will change that. You can see the difference between the internal driver and the gdal driver if you do

```
 library(raster)
 library(rgdal)
 a1 <- raster(filename, native=TRUE)
 a2 <- raster(filename, native=FALSE)
```